# How to write a generic method and its default equivalent in C#

Tags: c#, class, inheritance

I think this example is extremely simple and shows what I am trying to achieve:

```
public class A : A<object>
{
    // public static A GetInstance() => new A();
    // I can't do this, because cannot override static methods
}

public class A<T>
{
    public static A<T> GetInstance() => new A<T>();

    // public static A GetInstance() => new A();
    // can't do this, because it says that the method is already defined
}
```

I basically want to be able to use the method `GetInstance` in two ways:

- Specifying the type `T`: `A<T>.GetInstance()` or `A.GetInstance<T>()` (doesn't matter which one) - which should return the type `A<T>`
- Without specifying this type: `A.GetInstance()` - which should return the type `A`.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Strictly speaking, this is not a [generic method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/twcad0zb.aspx), but a non-generic method that belongs to a generic class.

Comment: Are you trying out the [abstract factory pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_factory_pattern)?

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov Hmm, not exactly. I am building a simple system for internal errors (gathering data what has happened during an execution of an operation). So if I only want to know if an operation is successful or had any errors, I would return Result.Failed(Error.Something); But if I also want to be able to return some specific data, I would do Result.Success<string>("hello");

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
using System;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        Console.WriteLine(A.GetInstance());
        Console.WriteLine(A<int>.GetInstance());
        Console.WriteLine(A.GetInstance<bool>());
        /*
            output :
            Program+A
            Program+A`1[System.Int32]
            Program+A`1[System.Boolean]
        */
    }
```

// classes

```
    public class A : A<object>
    {
        // non-generic method in non-generic class
        public static A GetInstance() 
        {
            return new A();
        }

        // generic method
        public static A<T> GetInstance<T>() 
        {
            return new A<T>();
        }
    }

    public class A<T>
    {
        // non-generic method in generic class
        public static A<T> GetInstance() 
        {
            return new A<T>();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
public class A<T>
{
    public static A<T> GetInstance()
    {
        return new A<T>();
    }
}

public class A : A<object>
{
    public static new A GetInstance()
    {
        return new A();
    }

    public static A<T> GetInstance<T>()
    {
        return new A<T>();
    }
}
```

Notice the `new` keyword to the left of the `A GetInstance()`.

Comment: Hmm... why this keyword?

Comment: It indicates to compiler that the override of non-virtual GetInstance() method (which is present in both base and derived class) is intentional. Basically, it removes the "... hides inherited member ..." warning in VS.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like this is what you want:

```
   public class A : A<object>
   {
       public static A<T> GetInstance<T>() => new A<T>();
       public new static A GetInstance() => new A();
   }

   public class A<T>
   {
       public static A<T> GetInstance() => new A<T>();
   }
```

Then use it like this:

```
   var a = A<int>.GetInstance();
   var b = A.GetInstance<int>();
   var c = A.GetInstance();
```

However, normally you'd expect to see generic types inherit from their non-generic equivalent, not the other way round (e.g. IEnumerable<T> : IEnumerable)

Answer (score 0):

```
void Main()
{
    var a = A.GetInstance();
    var b = A<object>.GetInstance();
    Console.WriteLine(a);
    Console.WriteLine(b);
}

class A<T>
{
    public static A<T> GetInstance()
    {
        return new A<T>();
    }
}

class A : A<object>
{
}
```

Comment: Thank you, but I am trying to return an object of type A<T>, not only T :) In the default case - only A

Answer (score 0):

How about just making a factory like :

```
public class Factory<T>
{
    public static A<T> Instance { get {return new A<T>(); } }
}
```